# T-SQL trigger and table name

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Inside a trigger I would like to know the name of the table on which the trigger was fired: si it possible to get it programmatically through T-SQL?

Comment: Stupid question: don't you know the table name when you create the trigger?

Comment: My question is not so stupid: think that you want to add the same trigger to all tables in your database with an automated sql batch, then you see that your code must not show a hard-coded table name, it has to rely on a self found table name in case you need that name, hasn't it?

Comment: well, the question remains even if  you are using an automated SQL batch: don't you know the table name in your trigger generator tool? I suppose you're iterating over all the table, etc...

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using @@procid eg

```
USE tempdb
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.triggerTest ( rowId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, someData VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NEWID() )
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.itrg_triggerTest  ON dbo.triggerTest
FOR INSERT
AS

--SELECT @@PROCID, OBJECT_NAME( @@PROCID ) 

SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME( parent_id ) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME( parent_id ) tableName FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = @@PROCID
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.triggerTest DEFAULT VALUES
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.triggerTest
GO
```